# Sum over every second cell if neighboring cell is not empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have created a timesheet in Excel to keep track of my working times. It all works pretty good, but I have one small problem.

My sheet has the following layout (`In`=started working, `Out`=stopped working):

```
A          | B     | C     | D     | E     | F     | G
-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------
Date       | In    | Out   | In    | Out   | In    | Out
01.03.2014 |       |       |       |       |       |       (weekend)
02.03.2014 |       |       |       |       |       |       (weekend)
03.03.2014 | 08:00 | 12:00 | 12:45 | 17:00 |       |
04.03.2014 | 08:45 | 13:30 | 13:45 | 17:45 |       |
05.03.2014 | 08:15 | 12:30 | 13:00 | 18:00 |       |
06.03.2014 | 08:00 | 12:30 | 13:00 | 17:30 |       |
...
```

Now I would like to calculate the time that I worked each day. That's easy:

```
= SUM($C2; $E2; $G2) - SUM($B2; $D2; $F2)
```

This will even work if I skip lunch sometimes like this:

```
A          | B     | C     | D     | E     | F     | G
-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------
Date       | In    | Out   | In    | Out   | In    | Out
01.03.2014 |       |       |       |       |       |       (weekend)
02.03.2014 |       |       |       |       |       |       (weekend)
03.03.2014 | 08:00 | 12:00 | 12:45 | 17:00 |       |
04.03.2014 | 08:45 |       |       | 17:45 |       |
05.03.2014 | 08:15 | 12:30 | 13:00 | 18:00 |       |
06.03.2014 | 08:00 | 12:30 | 13:00 | 17:30 |       |
...
```

But it does not work during the day when I entered the time I started working (`In`), but did not enter the time I stopped working (`Out`) yet:

```
A          | B     | C     | D     | E     | F     | G
-----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------
Date       | In    | Out   | In    | Out   | In    | Out
01.03.2014 |       |       |       |       |       |       (weekend)
02.03.2014 |       |       |       |       |       |       (weekend)
03.03.2014 | 08:00 | 12:00 | 12:45 | 17:00 |       |
04.03.2014 | 08:45 |       |       | 17:45 |       |
05.03.2014 | 08:15 | 12:30 | 13:00 | 18:00 |       |
06.03.2014 | 08:00 | 12:30 | 13:00 |       |       |
...
```

For `06.03.2014` this will result in a negative time.

What I would like to have is the time that I actually worked in the morning, i.e. `04:30` on `06.03.2014`. That means, I need to include only those columns into the second (negative) sum where the neighboring column is not empty. How can I do this in a general way which still supports skipping lunch time? With "general way" I mean a formula which would also work for columns F, G and possibly H, I... So it should not be a looong formula of `IF` statements.

I wanted to use the `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` function, but as far as I understood, it only accepts ranges like `B1:G1`, but it does not accept something like `B1;D1;F1`, i.e. skipping every second column. I have no idea how I can do that because I am no Excel expert at all... This is what I tried so far, but it does not work, it only gives me `#VALUE`:

```
= SUM($C2; $E2; $G2) - SUMIF(($C2; $E2; $G2); "<>"; ($B2; $D2; $F2))
```

This should mean: sum over C, E and G and subtract the sum of B, D and F if the corresponding cells in C, E and G are not empty. However, the parentheses around the ranges do not seem to work. Or is the problem something else?

Comment: Try using additional hidden columns to sum the results. For example, in R1 have "=IF(B1,B1,0)", in S1 have "=IF(D1,D1,0)" and then in U1 have =sum(R1:S1) and use that to tabulate results.

Comment: @ScottAndrewRogers Thanks for your suggestion. This might lead to a solution. However, in the end this is just splitting up a big formula into multiple columns. That is not what I want. There must be a neat solution to this problem. At least I hope... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took some inspiration from Madball's approach but without the need for an extra row. Use this for row 2 copied down

`=C2+E2+G2-B2-D2-F2+MOD(COUNT(B2:G2),2)*MAX(B2:G2)`

It add's/subtracts the times as required but adds **back** the latest time (thus ignoring it) when there is an odd number of times inserted.

Comment: Great! And so simple! It seems to work for all the cases I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, I modified it a little to make it easier to understand. I replaced `MOD` with `ISODD` because that's what we are checking: `=C2+E2+G2 - B2-D2-F2 + IF(ISODD(COUNT(B2:G2)), MAX(B2:G2), 0)`

Comment: @gehho, I suppose I'm stuck in the past! - I always avoided ISODD because in Excel 2003 and earlier versions it's an add-in function (Analysis ToolPak). In 2010, though, there's no problem

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do.  If further columns are inserted, the formula is easily adjusted:

1. Add, in row one, a series of 1,-1,1,-1...  This is used so that we know whether its an add or subtract.
2. At the far right (H in your example), use this formula:
   `=IF(ISODD(COUNT(B3:G3)),SUMPRODUCT($B$1:$G$1,B3:G3)+MAX(B3:G3),SUMPRODUCT($B$1:$G$1,B3:G3))`

This works in your example for every case (except weird things like leaving twice in a row):
[image]

Explanation:
SUMPRODUCT multiplies each cell in the array by its partner in the other array, and then adds it all together.  So, on 3/6, it does 8*-1+12:30*1+13:00*-1+17:30*1+0*-1+0*1.

If there are an odd number of ins/outs/ it adds back the last (highest) of the times to neutralize it.

Comment: +1 for a nice solution! However, I accepted barry houdini's answer because it is a lot simpler and even works without the additional row - which I did not like about your approach. Anyway, thanks a lot because your solution lead to the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but this works

[image]

I used a simple if statement

```
=SUM(IF(C2<>"",C2-B2,0),IF(E2<>"",E2-D2,0))
```

This will even do part days (such as row 4 where only an afternoon was worked).

If you were to add a third set of in/out, then update your formula according

```
=SUM(IF(C2<>"",C2-B2,0),IF(E2<>"",E2-D2,0),IF(G2<>"",G2-F2,0))
```

Comment: Right sorry, there was only one when I wrote the comment.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I had a similar solution in the beginning. However, this does not handle the case where I skip the lunch break, i.e. columns B and E are filled out, but C and D are not. See my example in the question.

Comment: I see... But, why would you just not put the out time in the cell which would make it work? Your OP doesn't state that that one of the options is a lunch break, and as such no implication that it is required? What would happen if you had lunch, but also a doctors appointment in the afternoon? Does this mean you'd need another set of in / out ?

Comment: I am also calculating the average of the in- and out-times. So if I enter `18:00` into column `C`, this will result in a wrong average for columns `C` and `E` because `C` is actually my column for "out for lunch". (However, you are right about the doctor visit... Probably, I should add ten more columns for unforeseen breaks. ;) ) I do not really need this, but I would like to have this. And I exptected to find a solution which may handle all those cases.

Comment: @gehho If I may, it seems like your approach is a little hacky - I'm concerned that your table will be very wide (and possibly confusing) and the formulae so complex it may not be manageable

Comment: @DaveRook Did you see the smiley behind my sentence about the additional ten columns? It was a joke, but I would really like to handle the (relatively common) case with the skipped lunch break.

Comment: ah, oops. I missed that, sorry  :)

Comment: BTW: Got my +1 anyway. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

Try this VBa

This is the result

[image]

This is not fully tested (other than what is shown in the screen shot)...

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    startingRow = 2' UPDATE THIS FOR THE STARTING ROW (in this example, I started on row 2 since row 1 is titles)
    numberOfRows = 6 ' UPDATE THIS FOR YOUR NUMBER OF ROWS

    For rowNumber = startingRow To numberOfRows

        Dim isContinuous As Boolean

        isContinuous = True

        Dim inCols(0 To 2) As Integer

        '65 is A, '66 is B etc

        inCols(0) = 66
        inCols(1) = 68
        inCols(2) = 70

        For Each inElement In inCols

            Dim totalTime As Integer

            If (Range(Chr(inElement) & rowNumber).Value <> "") Then
                Dim inDate As Date
                inDate = Range(Chr(inElement) & rowNumber).Value

                Dim outCols(0 To 2) As Integer

                outCols(0) = 67
                outCols(1) = 69
                outCols(2) = 71

                Dim hasOutValue As Boolean

                hasOutValue = False

                For Each outElement In outCols
                    If (inElement < outElement) Then
                        If (Range(Chr(outElement) & rowNumber).Value <> "") Then
                            Dim outDate As Date
                            outDate = Range(Chr(outElement) & rowNumber).Value
                            If (isContinuous = True) Then
                                totalTime = totalTime + DateDiff("h", inDate, outDate)
                            Else
                                totalTime = DateDiff("h", inDate, outDate)
                            End If

                            hasOutValue = True
                            Exit For
                        Else
                            isContinuous = False
                        End If

                    End If
                Next
                If hasOutValue = False Then
                    totalTime = 0
                End If

            End If

        Next
        Range("H" & rowNumber).Value = CStr(totalTime)
    Next rowNumber

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

How about you try and replace this:

```
= SUM($C2; $E2; $G2)
```

with this:

```
= SUM(IF($C2="";TEXT(NOW(); "hh:mm");$C2); IF($E2="";TEXT(NOW(); "hh:mm");$E2); IF($G2="";TEXT(NOW(); "hh:mm");$G2))
```

This formula should put current time in empty cells ($C2,$E2,$G2), which should give you more real working time. After all, you are working untill now, arent you?

Comment: How will this work if he wants to review another days working hours?

Comment: Well, shouldn't past days have already input numbers? I was thinking that he talked about current day, where he did not put Out time because he did not exit yet.